# is Java 9 compatibility with hibernate 4.3.5.Final?

Tags: quarkus

my java app is using the hibernate 4.3.5.Final, and it works fine on java 8

but on java9 it don't work => my question

is Java 9 compatibility with hibernate 4.3.5.Final?

Comment: You tagged this question with quarkus but your question seem to be about hibernate ?

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate ORM 4.3 Series is compatible with Java 6 or 7.
https://hibernate.org/orm/releases/4.3/

Comment: tks for your replying. But on java8 it works fine.
but on java9 it does not work. At your link it works only java6+7, but really it works on java8(why that :)),

Comment: The Java versions mentioned in this link are the ones Hibernate ORM was designed to work with, and the ones against which it was tested. Other versions may work to a limited extent, but there's no guarantee. So for Java 8 you were lucky, and not for Java 9. If you want Java 9, just upgrade to a newer version of Hibernate ORM.

Comment: tks for your replying, I think like you so